# Java print api ZPL support

Tags: java, printing, zpl, java-print

Is it possible to print using zpl through java print api?

In my print application i usually send pdf contents for printing to the printers. I want the support for printing using zpl. Is it possible to pass the zpl in the print api for printing?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://coolcheatsheet.com/question/print-zpl-from-java)?

Comment: Do you mean zpl as the protocol for zebra printers?

Comment: ZPL is printed/sended best as plain text to the printer.